# Automatic Anchor Docusign Tab

Tags: docusignapi

I tried added "Automatic Anchor Docusign Tab" text to flat pdf. 
I include text with:

\s1\

\t1\

\n1\

\d1\

DocuSignSignHere

[image]

But did not get DocuSign tabs when I use SOAP API method SendDocument. 
Result page:
[image]

How enable for DocuSign account "Automatic Anchor Docusign Tab"? Should it be enable by API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the DocuSign automatic anchor tags only work through the DocuSign for Salesforce manage package.

However, you can specify specific tag anchors via SOAP under the tab settings. More information can be found [here.](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending%20Group/Tab.htm?Highlight=anchor)